# Extending JSON Scheme for data policy

Tags: database, hash, jsonschema, policy

I am wondering whether it is possible to extend json schema to be aware of data policy that I set. For example, some confidential data are hashed automatically before saving to database, things like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your hash logic results in a value that is verifiable, you may be able to derive a RegEx and use the `regex` keyword.  This is available out of the box.

Regarding extending JSON Schema, it depends on the implementation and the draft you are using.  Drafts 2019-09 and 2020-12 support vocabularies, which are well-defined sets of keywords.  You can create custom keywords this way.  Additionally, some implementations let you create custom keywords independent well-defined vocabs.

You'll need to check with the implementation to see what it supports.

Comment: It doesn't but it can identify data that needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema is not designed for and does not support modifying data. It is a validation and annotation tool.

Having said that, you could use annotation results to modify the data after validation.

You may find it simpler to use another tool for doing this though, such as `jq`
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/